# how to get a class name inside the Ext.select('.classname') and remove one of the divs from within-EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to check if a class exists inside this parent class:

```
var index = 1;
Ext.select(".test").elements[index];
```

here is the o/p from above:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3">
      <div class="hidden"></div>
      <div class="hidden"></div>
      <div class="hidden"></div>
      <div class="hidden"></div>
      <div class="hidden"></div>
      <div class="remove-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now im trying to find which of the divs with `class="div3`"  does not have a child with `class="hidden"` and I want to remove that `div` with `class="remove-child"` and replace it with another div, say `<div class="new-child"></div>`, so that o/p would be:

```
<div class="parent">
      <div class="div1"></div>
      <div class="div2"></div>
      <div class="div3">
          <div class="hidden"></div>
          <div class="hidden"></div>
          <div class="hidden"></div>
          <div class="hidden"></div>
          <div class="hidden"></div>
          <div class="new-child"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a not selector to match the child(ren) and replace:

```
Ext.select('.div3 > :not(.hidden)').replaceWith({
    cls: 'new-child',
    html: 'New'
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2l46).